# Como remover valor após ponto flutuante

Tags: javascript, ponto-flutuante

Tenho o trecho de código exposto abaixo:

```js
var calcularSoma = function (primeiroValor, segundoValor) {
var soma = primeiroValor + segundoValor;
if (soma < 10) {
 console.log(soma, "Unidades.");
 return soma;
} else if (soma < 100) {
 var restoUnidade = soma % 10;
 var dezena = soma / 10;
 if (restoUnidade == 1 && dezena <= 1) {
  console.log(dezena, "Dezena. e ", restoUnidade, "Unidade");
 } else {
  console.log(dezena, "Dezenas. e ", restoUnidade, "Unidades");
 }
 return soma;
} else if (soma < 1000) {
 var centena = soma / 100;
 console.log(centena, "Centenas.");
 return soma;
} else {
 var milhar = soma / 1000;
 console.log(milhar, "Milhar.");
 return soma;
}
}

calcularSoma(5, 10);
```

**1.** O que eu pretendo é exibir o resultado no plural caso os valores contido nas variáveis sejam maiores do que 1. Irei implementar as condições abaixo, no momento preciso entender primeiramente qual implementação representará a lógica exposta.

**2.** Preciso formatar o valor exibido, nesse exemplo é exibido o valor `1.5 Dezenas e 5 Unidades.`(plural de Unidade, pois o resto foi maior que 1), queria exibir algo como: `1 Dezena e 5 Unidades.`

**3.** Aqui utilizei `if(restoUnidade == 1 && dezena <= 1)` pois nesse exemplo acima o valor da variável dezena em tese é maior que 1, embora seja um decimal.

**P.S.:** Se possível me digam qual a melhor forma de expor a dúvida, primeiro o código seguindo das dúvidas(como exposto nesse post), ou as dúvidas primeiro seguida do código?

Comment: conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Ao me ver você precisa adicionar mais alguns **ifs**.

O problema pode estar no `if (restoUnidade == 1 && dezena <= 1)`

Não compreendi muito bem o que você quer, mas vê se isso te ajuda.
Modifica esse trecho no código:

```
else if (soma < 100) {
  var restoUnidade = soma % 10;
  var dezena = soma / 10;
  if (restoUnidade == 1) {
    if (dezena <= 1) {
      console.log(dezena, "Dezena. e ", restoUnidade, "Unidade");
    } else {
      console.log(dezena, "Dezenas. e ", restoUnidade, "Unidade");
    }
  } else if (dezena > 1) {
    console.log(dezena, "Dezenas. e ", restoUnidade, "Unidade");
  } else {
    console.log(dezena, "Dezena. e ", restoUnidade, "Unidade");
  }
  return soma;
}
```